# Llamada telefonica con html5 en android

Tags: android, html, href

Tengo una aplicación en `asp.net` y quiero hacer una llamada telefónica con un `<a>llamar</a>` pero cuando agrego la extensión y las opciones para cada tipo de llamada el equipo android elimina las comillas y todo lo que sigue después.

Ya intente con hexadecimal pero lo elimina de igual manera, el * y el # si funcionan bien no se porque la coma no. Ya lo intente directamente en el html y con javascript y no funciona, en ios si funciona.

Ya se probo en varios navegadores firefox,chrome,navegador de samsung

En la computadora las comas si aparecen al dar clic al vinculo en el navegador

Ejemplo:

`<a href="tel:+521212121212,96000#,109837#,2#,1">+521212121212</a>`

y en el telefono se abre una pagina web, se da clic en el link y el telefono muestra +521212121212

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola user. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Recuerda leer el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio.  Puedes explicar mejor tu situacion? Con ejemplos de lo que introduces y lo que el equipo android recive o modifica. Un saludo

Comment: En android usar chrome? o algun otro?

Comment: ya lo probe en un android diferente version y aun sin funcionar, diferente navegador y solo cuando abro la aplicacion del telefono le elimina la coma o hay otra forma de abrir la app del telefono?

Comment: saben si puede existir algun lanzador externo o como una app que haga esto pero de una manera sencilla.

Comment: o como se podria hacer que el android me pregunte con que app abrir la app y asi seleccionar el telefono?